# tested python program fails when run from cron on Raspi

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, cron, popen

I have a python program on a RASP PI 2B [Jessie lite] that runs just fine from the terminal command line. However, when trying to run from cron it fails as discussed below.  I have set up mta and logging.

from syslog:

> Jan 20 15:10:01 carlton CRON[2189]:
>   (pi) CMD (python amr_water_r9c.py carl1022_104  1541513276  > $HOME/log/logfile 2>&1)

the python program  launches two tasks using POPEN with

the first task starts ok

```
proc1=subprocess.Popen(['rtl_tcp'],shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

the second task

```
proc2=subprocess.Popen(arg_rtlamr)
```

results in :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "amr_water_r9c.py", line 153, in <module>
    main()
  File "amr_water_r9c.py", line 148, in main
    get_data()
  File "amr_water_r9c.py", line 99, in get_data
    proc2=subprocess.Popen(arg_rtlamr)          
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

where

arg_rtlamr  is defined as :

```
   = ['rtlamr','-format=csv', '-unique=true', \
     '-duration=1m',\
     '-msgtype='+msgtype,'-filterid='+meter_num , \
     ' > $HOME/data/elecamr' ]
```

permissions are:

```
pi@carlton:~/gopath/bin $ ls -l
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi 4079128 Jan 18 16:42 rtlamr

pi@carlton:~/data $ ls -l
-rw-rw-rw- 1 pi pi 78 Jan 20 14:03 elecamr
pi@carlton:~/log $ ls -l
-rw-rw-rw- 1 pi pi 483 Jan 20 15:10 logfile
```

Greatly appreciate any clue as to what is going on
john

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cron jobs are usually run under a different environment. For example, PATH might not be set to the value as you expected.

Comment: thnaks finally figured that out. Was misled seeing the first POPEN work without specifying a path, but that was a apt-get install, where the second was a golang install to pi and the path in .bashrc. appreciate your help